# What is the difference between using "эту", "этот" or "эта"?

Tags: грамматика

If I want to say:

1) I have a bag - у меня есть сумка

2) I need this bag - мне нужна эта сумка

**(Why I can't say я нужна эта сумка and I need "мне"?)**

3) I want this bag - я хочу эту сумку

**(Why is not я хочу эта сумка? and why if I use scarf and not bag I need to use этот? Like я хочу этот шарф )**

Comment: They are called demonstrative pronouns; this is where I learned them and where I think is the best source:
http://russianlearn.com/grammar/category/demonstrative_pronouns

Comment: "Я нужна" - "I am needed". "Мне нужна" - "I need"

Comment: yes, opposite to English

Answer (score 7):

2. Because this is how Russian works.

The need of a speaker in Russian is normally expressed indirectly through Dative case

**`мне требуется / необходима`**

This is likely because someone's need is perceived in Russian not as an act or volition, but as a state. Unlike at least in English the actor here is not the person who needs but the object which is needed.
That's why in the sentence **`Мне нужна эта сумка`** the subject is **`эта сумка`**. It's as if the bag were acting upon yourself making you need it.

It's possible to say **`я нуждаюсь в этой сумке`** but the verb **`нуждаться`** is a little stronger than **`to need`**, it means that you can't do without it or that you pine for it, which is a volition.

3. The verb **`хотеть`** governs Accusative case for inanimate objects, therefore **`сумка`** assumes the form of **`сумку`** as expected of it in Accusative.

3A. **`Шарф`** is a masculine noun inflected in Accusative, the masculine demonstrative pronoun **`этот`** must agree with it in grammatical case, hence **`этот`**, which is its form in both Nominative and Accusative cases.

**`Cумка`** (**`cумку`** in Accusative) on the other hand is a feminine noun therefore it requires feminine demonstrative pronoun **`эта`** whose inflected form in Accusative case is **`эту`**.

Comment: "Ты нужна?" - "Да, я нужна" :)

Comment: @Alexander true, this warrants a more nuanced explanation